# How to diff two commits or files on a remote repository with git?

Tags: git, diff, dvcs

I have two hashes and an URL of a git remote repository. How to perform a diff?

With SVN I do it this way:

```
svn diff -rXXX:YYY svn+ssh://host/path
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible without cloning the entire repository beforehand, due to the way git works. After cloning you can create the diff like this:

```
git diff <from>..<to> -- <filename>
```

`<from>` and `<to>` may be some “commitish”, so tags, branches and everything else that can be resolved to a commit will work as well.

---

If you want to save some traffic and know for sure that both commits are inside the last hundred commits you may use:

```
git clone --depth 100 <repository>
```

This will only clone the newest 100 commits. Please note that it will be impossible to push or pull from this clone afterwards!

Comment: Could you add a short comment why a diff cannot be done directly on the remote repository? I have read about the design of git, perhaps on a too high level, and still cannot think of any reason.

Comment: @JohnnyBaloney A diff can be done on the remote repository, but not by any external means. There are several protocols available for git, among them some rather dumb ones (e.g. dump HTTP, there is better HTTP by now). Dump HTTP does not know about git in any way, it simply delivers the objects. But aside from this, this probably simply was a design decision.